# DVI to HDMI cable problem

Tags: tv, cable, dvi

I connect my PC to my TV using a DVI to HDMI cable. The problem is that if the resolution is higher than 720p, the image on the TV screen starts to deteriorate ( you can clearly see small green dots all over low light places).

The same thing is happening both in Windows and Mac OS X, so that rules out drivers and hardware on the PC side. I also know the Tv is capable of displaying crisp 1080p images, so that only leaves the cable. Are there any bandwidth limitations for such a connection? Or is the cable just faulty? Do you have any experiences with this type of setup?

Comment: issues with DVI > HDMI on TVs don't seem to be uncommon. cable length, cable quality, overscan problems with the TV are possible causes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going for faulty cable. Because I've the same setup. DVI from my GPU to HDMI in my TV. Working perfectly in 1080p.

Comment: What kind of cable do you use?

Comment: A cheap HDMI 1.3c one. It cost me 5 bucks. Just because it's cheap doesn't mean it's bad. Bad luck is bad luck and faulty cables can happen whether it cost 5 or 50 bucks.

Comment: BUT! the signal starts to deteriorate after 10m (or 7m? I'm not completely sure!) length. So if you have it running at more than 10m you need an active repeater of some sort.

Comment: @NoCanDo I'll have to agree with you that it's a faulty cable.

Answer (score 0):

What is the length of the DVI and HDMI cables? If the cable is very long, you will need to replace it with either a shorter cable, or a cable that is properly sheilded, or add a repeated/signal extender.

Also check for faulty cables, faulty CVI<=>HDMI connector, as well as your graphics card.

Comment: It's only 2m, I don't think the length is an issue.

Comment: Well that the same problem is happening on two different operating systems doesn't rule out the PC side hardware problem. Did you already try a different cable and connecting the PC to another display?